# Creating Double Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

Can I get to know what is happening in the following commands?
Here we have `H` as a structure with `n` as an integer type structure element. What is `var` basically after this?

```
float **var;
var = new float* [H.n];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "basically"? What's your question?

Comment: You're doing something too hard. Start with something simpler. Do you understand what `int * p = new int[10];` does, and what the value of `p` is?

Comment: `var` is "basically" a mess after this.

Answer (score 0):

`H.n` is presumably an integer, for example `10`

```
float **var = new float*[10];
```

To simplify, you can create an alias for `float*`, call it `pfloat`:

```
typedef float* pfloat;
pfloat *var = new pfloat[10];
```

So that's just 10 pointers. Each pointer can be allocated to create a separate array, resulting in 2D array:

```
//initialize 10 x 20 array:
float **var = new float*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    var[i] = new float[20];

//use:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        var[i][j] = i * 20 + j + 0.1f;
        cout << var[i][j] << "\n";
    }
}

//cleanup:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    delete[]var[i];
delete[]var;
```